# Purpose of OR EAX,0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: assembly

I have read the assembly line

```
OR EAX, 0xFFFFFFFF
```

and in the register `EAX` the program has stored a string. I have problems to understand how we can make a comparison with a string and a value like that.
After performing that instruction, `EAX` has the value `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Can someone tell me which purpose that operation has ? Is it a line which comes frequently in an assembly code ? (for example the line `XOR EAX, EAX` which is an efficient way to make `EAX = 0` ? Is it something like that ?)

Comment: could have been done to affect flags. Data move instructions don't generally affect flags

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that in order to understand why the compiler does this, study the following disassembly:

```
B8 FF FF FF FF                          mov     eax, 0FFFFFFFFh
83 C8 FF                                or      eax, 0FFFFFFFFh
```

What the compiler is trying to accomplish is probably to set the `eax` register to -1 using as few bytes as possible in order to be cache friendly. `OR` also has about twice the throughput of the `MOV` instruction as long as you don't mind messing up the flags.

This is probably a variable being initialized to -1.

Comment: It's quite common to use -1 to indicate an error or some other special reserved value if 0 is considered a valid value in the range. I'm speculating of course.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned strings, it is also feasible that `strcmp` or its brethren is involved, and -1 could be an ordinary return value in that case. But I agree, it's impossible to give a non-speculative answer to "*why*" without seeing what input generates this result, and how that result is used later in the code.

Comment: @DCoder very true. It could be a completely normal return value from a comparison function with -1 (<0) as less, 0 as equal and 1 (>0) as greater which wouldn't be uncommon either.

Comment: @user3097712 `-1` is expressed as `0xFFFFFFFF` (all bits set) in a 2-complement way.

Comment: *"OR also has about twice the throughput of the MOV instruction as long as you don't mind messing up the flags."* Well, no, that's not true. As far as the CPU is concerned, `or eax, -1` depends on the previous value of the `eax` register, which lengthens the code's dependency chain and will significantly decrease performance compared to if you had used a `mov`. There *is* a code size reduction, as you demonstrated, but there is a very significant speed reduction. It is almost never worth the 2 bytes. (Yes, chips *could* conceivably special-case an OR with all bits set, but they don't.)

Comment: @PeterAndersson you should really add that note from glglgl in the answer. For instance, FORTH uses -1 to refer to true. It helps for me to think of this optimization as a quick way to set all the bits to 1.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I can't post this as a comment but a couple of quick (and non-exhaustive) tests show the following:

- gcc (4.6.3) uses `or` instead of `mov` when optimising for size (`/Os`)
- msvc (13) uses `or` instead of `mov` whatever the optimisation setting (including disabled)
- clang (3.0) uses `mov` whatever the optimisation setting

gcc's behaviour, in particular, supports Peter Andersson's answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't thought to use `/Os` with gcc, but of course that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Surprising results: [MSVC CL19 emits `or` with `/O2` but `mov` with `/Os`. ICC 17 and Clang 4.0 use `xor eax, eax, dec eax` when optimizing for size](https://godbolt.org/g/H1rDWO)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The surprise is because `/Os` (like its cousin, `/Ot`) must be combined with `/Og` to enable optimization in MSVC. Otherwise, it's completely ignored. :-) And your example is not a particularly good test case. Under normal circumstances, when -1 is needed in a register within a larger block of code, `/O1` will cause MSVC to emit an `OR`, whereas `/O2` will cause MSVC to emit a `MOV`. I can only assume it always uses `OR` here because it's not worried about any sort of data dependency on `EAX` slowing down performance, considering the relative overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 5):

This will always result in setting the `EAX` register equal to 0xFFFFFFFF and will also have the side effect of setting the flags appropriately (that is N=1, Z=0, etc.).  It is not a common idiom.

Comment: What is the `N` flag (Carry, Overflow, Zero, etc are expected, but what does N represent)?

Comment: "... it is not a common idiom" - its actually quite common, especially in older software. The `OR` instruction is smaller than the `MOV` instruction. A machine with 640K or 1MB or memory needed the savings (yep, it dates back that far). And `XOR` was (and still is) used to zero a register for the same reason.

Comment: @jww: Sorry, I work with a lot of different processors. I meant the SF (sign flag) which is what Intel calls it; other manufacturers call it N for Negative.  It might be useful to the OP if you could specify compilers which generate that sequence.  None of the ones I have handy do so.

Comment: @jww: thanks for your explanation. I did not know the fact that OR is smaller than MOV. Now i know it. Thanks! From this posting, I have learn a lot.